DAX ISFILTERED function with page level filters
I'm using a page level filter (which users do not see), where I filter out irrelevant values:

I also add this filter to the page for the users:

I have a lot of filters on my page, so I use bookmarks to show/hide the filter pane. But I would still like to display what the user selected. So I created the following measure to show:

"Selected filter: All" if all values are selected
"Selected filter: Value 1" if "Value 1" is the only one selected (same for the other values)
"Selected filter: Multiple" if multiple values are selected (but not all)

.
MyMeasure = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    NOT(ISFILTERED(Example[Filter])),"Selected filter: ALL",
    HASONEVALUE(Example[Filter]),"Selected filter: " & SELECTEDVALUE(Example[Filter]),
    "Selected filter: Multiple"
)

This works just fine if I remove the page level filter:

But I do want to remove the "(Blank)" and "empty" value in the filter pane. And when I do that it does not work:

I guess it is because the ISFILTERED(Example[Filter]) still recognizes that it is filtered on the page level filter.
Is there somehow to overcome this issue?

ISFILTERED() is working as designed. I would approach this by using COUNTROWS() instead. Get a distinct count of all rows, get a count of selected rows and then compare the two accounting for the number you are manually filtering in the page filter.
As an aside, if you have (blank) showing in your dimension, it suggests some remodelling and data cleaning is required.
